# Amdgpu doesn't display anything till KDE Desktop is shown

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, amd-graphics, amdgpu, sddm

I use Kubuntu and switched from a legacy Nvidia Card to an AMD GPU rx6600 and removed the nouveau drivers. I also made sure that xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu is installed and everything seems fine on the Desktop, but on boot till sddm I can see the Display not getting a signal. I can still type in my password and then finally see something on Display.

Using the iGPU from intel works to see the whole boot process and sddm.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks